# Typescript version in ASP.NET 5 project

Tags: angularjs, typescript, asp.net-core

Attempting to follow allow with the AngularJS 2 quick start demo for typescript in an ASP.NET 5 project.  I get an error in my app.component.ts file that a feature is a typescript 1.5 feature, current version is 1.0.

[image]

Yet I've installed The typescript extension for 1.7.3, which you can see when I run "tsc -v"

[image]

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "version": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: it looks like you imported es6-shim.d.ts twice. can you check that?

Comment: I added the details of my package.json.  es6-shim is not added twice, though it could potentially be a dependency in any of those other libraries.

Comment: that might be it, maybe do a search and remove one of them?

Comment: the conflict is between lib.es6.d.ts and es6-shim.d.ts.  lib.es6.d.ts appears to be a part of TS1.7, it's located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts

Comment: so, remove the es6-shim from package.json? :D

Comment: maybe the fact that you are transpiling to es6 not es5 has something to do with it too?

Comment: changing "target": "es6" to "target": "es5" in tsconfig.json fixed my es6 error.  Thank you!  Still not transpiling my app.component.ts for some reason.. maybe another problem with my tsconfig.json?

Comment: well, you can make an answer for this problem with this solution. if you need help with another error please ask another question. :)

Comment: uhm, can you check the properties window of the project, to see if there's a typescript version somewhere? Maybe it's set to 1 by default.